# Is there no way to get Google Calendar to show all my task lists at once?

Tags: google-calendar

Right now I use only one Task List in Google Calendar because you can only view one task list at a time. I'd really like to be able to have all my task lists viewable so that I can colour code them and see which tasks are related to different projects and visually see how I'm balancing my time between them.

As far as I can tell, though, Google doesn't offer this function, and from what I've seen from looking on the web, it seems Google is completely unresponsive to user requests for this feature, just as they are completely unresponsive to almost all user engagement.

So, is there a hack, or plug in or anything that I can do so that I can either view different task lists at the same time, or at least assign different colours to different tasks?

Answer (score -2):

You can use https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/157979 to color individual tasks that have certain keywords you specify in the script.

Comment: How does this solve the original problem of viewing tasks from multiple lists?